# Where to find Sleuth's Span.TRACE_ID_NAME replacement after migration to spring boot 2.x?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm migrating my service from spring boot 1.5.2 to 2.0.5. Somewhere in the code i used the following Sleuth's constant

```
org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span.TRACE_ID_NAME
```

After migration there is no such constant and code doesn't compile. I tried to search for all symbols in the classpath named TRACE_ID_NAME and found only private or package members.

The question is: what is legal replacement for it.

Answer (score 1):

The values are the same. Your can check out Brave's B3 Propagation Factory that contains all the values set up.

Comment: Did you mean B3Propagation class? Cannot find B3 Propagation Factory.

Comment: Yeah if that one contains the fields with the headers then that's the one